# How to fully remove saltstack (salt) from linux

Tags: salt-stack

I recently installed salt on my Linux (salt-master, salt-minion, salt-ssh, salt-syndic, salt-cloud and salt-api). After some practice, I want to completely remove salt from my system, so I can re-install a clean version (with none of my mistakes while practising using it).

Is there a way of removing salt and any related files/folders from my system?

Comment: It depends how you installed it, and on what system.

Comment: @OrangeDog I followed the instructions on https://docs.saltproject.io/salt/install-guide/en/latest/topics/install-by-operating-system/ubuntu.html (Jammy)

Comment: `sudo apt purge salt-*`